# How to format a code block as is done by github's gist embed?

Tags: github, jekyll, gist

I have a Jekyll-powered blog, oriented towards programming for data analysis. I often embed github gists to display nicely formatted (highlighted) code blocks, and this works perfectly.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to generate (locally on my machine) the same html code that's generated by the github gist embed, but for code files that are located on my computer instead of in github gist repo.

I guess my question could then be rephrased as: 
- The html code that a 'github-gist embed' gives, how is it generated in the first place?

FYI: I'm not necessarily looking for a closed solution, any pointers on how to achieve this would also be very appreciated.

Comment: What about using code within your post? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Rafael: Thanks for your answer. For sure, I could do that, but for aesthetic consistency I would like for it to be formatted *exactly* as github gist embeds. 

It's actually more than that what I'm trying to achieve. I tend to post Jupyter notebooks, and I would like to have the notebook's code cells to e formatted like that, as well.